# How to downgrade Yeoman on linux using npm

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, yeoman, yo

How do I downgrade Yeoman? Version 5.0.0 seems, as of now, unstable and has issues with some generators. The suggested solution is to downgrade yeoman to version 4.3.1. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't downgrade Yeoman directly; instead, we can uninstall then re-install the desired version.

For Linux:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g yo
sudo npm install -g yo@version
```

For Windows:

```
npm uninstall -g yo
npm install -g yo@version
```

Comment: Does not work. this whole toolset is a dependency nightmare.